# notifyDataSetChanged() does not refresh my ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to delete items from a `ListView`. However, after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, my `ListView` does not refresh, and instead refreshes AFTER I click on the `EditText`. I have also tried using the adapter.remove method, but that produced the same error. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
public class AddWordActivity extends Activity {
private static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,       
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, words);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordsListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, final int position, long id) {
            words.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: you should use adapter.remove(position) instead of words.remove(pos).

Comment: if you do words.remove(position) you will need to re-initialize your adapter and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to notify underlying view to refresh. But if you do adapter.remove(position) as suggested by @Raj3227522 you can simply call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after that as your have changed the adapter directly and not the arraylist being used.

Comment: where you set words value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented in my code like this and it works for me

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MyAdatper adapter=(MyAdatper)parent.getAdapter();
                adapter.remove(myStringArray.get(position));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I swear I already tried this, but I guess I made a typo or something.

Answer (score 0):

you should use adapter.remove(position) instead of words.remove(position).
and if you want to use word.remove(position) then you need to set adapter again to ListView as there is changed data in ArrayList words.  otherwise you can use adapter.remove(pos); method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added items in ArrayList? Kindly add the idem otherwise your code is perfect.

Comment: where you have called that method please show your code

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "words" array list will be local to your item listener. So instead of trying to remove the value from words, try removing it from the adapter itself. Cheers :)